# grails setting value to hidden field

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to have a `hiddenfield` with the value of the current user logged in.

I know how to get the current user logged in. `<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" />`

But how can i set it to a hidden field ?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple enough. Something like this perhaps:

```
<input type="hidden" name="whateverYouWant" value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}" />
```

Or if you prefer to use the hiddenField tag:

```
<g:hiddenField name="whateverYouWant" value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}" />
```

Comment: May i also know, how can i get the User object. I need to pass the entire user Object and is there a way i could do this from the GSP file ?